# how to detect voice-call feature in phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

is it possible to determine if the device is capable of phone calls via Phonegap? 
especially for Android and iOS devices

my first thought was to determine if the app is running on tablet or cell-phone, but there are tables with phone voice-call feature, though...

thanks

Igor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way/plugin to do this with PhoneGap/Cordova. PhoneGap/Cordova gives you access to the devices network information. Please see this plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information/blob/master/doc/index.md , with this you could at least get what type of connection the device has.

So if there is no connection then you cannot make calls. Doesn't solve your problem but might help.

Extra: Please note that you cannot make in app calls with android it has to open the native call app.